# Can someone explain this Javascript Tabs Code

Tags: javascript, arrays, accordion, indexof

Copied from [HERE](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/js-tabs) & Modified by me

I know what some codes are doing, but not whole (I think Arrow Functions & Loops are confusing me), As I'm still a noob in Javascript

***Actually I want to simplify this code, so that it relay mainly on*** `indexOf` ***function (not on any hard coded html code) like:***

- onClick of :nth number of child *of* **`.tab-stripe`**

  - Remove `active` class on sibling childs *of* **`.tab-stripe`**
  - Remove `active` class on sibling childs *of* **`.tab-contents`**
  - Add `active` class on **clicked child**
  - Add `active` class on same :nth number of child *of* **`.tab-contents`**
- Also Set tab active based on #url parameter coming from **ID** of childs of **`.tab-contents`**

```
<div class="tab-contents">
    <div id="Tab1" class="tab-content">Lorem ipsum</div> https://example.com/#Tab1
    <div id="Tab2" class="tab-content">Lorem ipsum</div> https://example.com/#Tab2
</div>
```

but since I'm not able to understand this, I can't do that

My Questions

> Q1: is `...` necessary in array
> Q2: what actually is `current_tab_index` in whole code & why does its value is negative
> Q3: what is going on here `=== -1 ? 0 :`
> Q4: why  `i`  is written as `forEach((x, i)` & what would be the value of `i`, SINCE its argument  `(index)` is written so much times
> Q5: what is/would be the value of `x`

```js
function tabify(element) {
    const stripe = element.querySelector(".tabs-stripe");
    const content = element.querySelector(".tabs-content");
    const tab_stripes = [...stripe.children]; //Q1
    const tab_contents = [...content.children];
    let current_tab_index = -1; //Q2

    function setTab(index) {
        if (current_tab_index > -1) {
            tab_stripes[current_tab_index].classList.remove("active");
            tab_contents[current_tab_index].classList.remove("active");
        }

        tab_stripes[index].classList.add("active");
        tab_contents[index].classList.add("active");
        current_tab_index = index;
    }

    default_tab_index = tab_stripes.findIndex((x) => {
        return [...x.classList].indexOf("active") > -1;
    });

    default_tab_index = default_tab_index === -1 ? 0 : default_tab_index; //Q3
    setTab(default_tab_index);
    tab_stripes.forEach((x, i) => (x.onclick = (event) => setTab(i))); //Q4
}

// this is where the magic happens!
[...document.querySelectorAll(".tabs-container")].forEach((x) => tabify(x)); //Q5
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

body {
    font-family: Google Sans;
    font-variant: tabular-nums;
}

sup {
    font-size: 10px;
}

.tabs-container {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    border: 2px solid #b3b3b3;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.tabs-stripe {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    overflow: auto;
    user-select: none;
}

.tabs-stripe > li {
    flex-grow: 1;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #f0f0f0;
}

.tabs-stripe > li.active {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: none;
}

.tabs-stripe > li + li {
    border-left: 2px solid #b3b3b3;
}

.tabs-content {
    height: calc(100% - 51px);
}

.tab {
    padding: 20px;
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.tab.active {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs-container">
    <ul class="tabs-stripe">
        <li>1<sup>0</sup></li>
        <li>2<sup>1</sup></li>
        <li>3<sup>2</sup></li>
        <li class="active">4<sup>3</sup></li>
        <li>5<sup>4</sup></li>
        <li>6<sup>5</sup></li>
        <li>7<sup>6</sup></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="tabs-content">
        <li id="Tab1-Q1" class="tab">
            <center>Tab 1<sup>0</sup> Content</center><br/>
            What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard
            dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
            survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the
            1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus
            PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </li>
        <li id="Tab1-Q2" class="tab">
            <center>Tab 2<sup>1</sup> Content</center><br/>
            Tristique senectus et netus et. Enim praesent elementum facilisis leo vel. Aliquam faucibus purus in massa tempor nec. Eu lobortis elementum
            nibh tellus molestie. Ullamcorper a lacus vestibulum sed. Mattis nunc sed blandit libero volutpat sed cras. Mus mauris vitae ultricies leo
            integer malesuada. Etiam erat velit scelerisque in dictum non consectetur a. Commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis. Sed
            vulputate odio ut enim blandit volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit. Quis auctor elit sed vulputate. Sit amet mauris commodo quis imperdiet.
            Sed viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum enim.
        </li>
        <li id="Tab1-Q3" class="tab">
            <center>Tab 3<sup>2</sup> Content</center><br/>
            Mi sit amet mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa tincidunt. Morbi tincidunt augue interdum velit euismod in. Eget nulla facilisi etiam
            dignissim diam quis enim lobortis. Justo donec enim diam vulputate ut pharetra. Tincidunt arcu non sodales neque. Nec feugiat in fermentum
            posuere. Volutpat consequat mauris nunc congue nisi vitae. Suspendisse sed nisi lacus sed viverra tellus in hac habitasse. Dolor purus non
            enim praesent elementum. Mattis pellentesque id nibh tortor id aliquet lectus proin. Bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel. Nunc sed velit
            dignissim sodales ut eu sem integer. Sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus nec feugiat in. Pulvinar neque laoreet suspendisse
            interdum. Magna eget est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing.
        </li>
        <li id="Tab1-Q4" class="tab active">
            <center>Tab 4<sup>3</sup> Content</center><br/>
            Commodi corporis praesentium sapiente cum est, aliquam, libero veniam minus voluptatem officiis odio. Asperiores molestiae explicabo facere
            quia! Possimus ipsum est doloremque accusamus similique non eligendi repellendus? Asperiores illum voluptates sequi reprehenderit quam sunt
            accusamus quo sint tempore perspiciatis facere in, odio dolore dolores obcaecati aut inventore! Veritatis eos facere dolor iure id mollitia
            nisi dicta. Culpa velit ut sequi, nam similique doloribus numquam vitae dolor. Sit cumque et sunt sapiente? Minus quidem reiciendis et,
            harum excepturi esse deserunt eos eligendi ex pariatur, sit, dolorem suscipit architecto praesentium fugit. Possimus nesciunt animi
            aspernatur eveniet delectus incidunt ipsa at illo explicabo! .
        </li>
        <li id="Tab1-Q5" class="tab">
            <center>Tab 5<sup>4</sup> Content</center><br/>
            Dicta ratione magni mollitia assumenda sed enim doloribus repudiandae. Mollitia illo consectetur in iure neque. Non dolore culpa doloremque
            similique natus fuga hic voluptates, temporibus itaque. Hic accusantium quasi atque beatae laborum dolor tempora facere quibusdam animi
            vitae sint exercitationem impedit asperiores consequuntur, eius mollitia deleniti ad eligendi nobis ullam dignissimos sequi at natus earum.
            Officiis, expedita dolore fuga doloremque consequuntur aliquam facilis odit optio modi. Exercitationem dolor reiciendis, aperiam et
            excepturi molestias, cumque ex vel tenetur blanditiis ad eum nesciunt cupiditate autem doloribus quam vero maxime, distinctio sit inventore
            itaque aliquid. Obcaecati architecto odio qui dolore .
        </li>
        <li id="Tab1-Q6" class="tab">
            <center>Tab 6<sup>5</sup> Content</center><br/>
            Placeat, reprehenderit eaque? Totam perspiciatis expedita praesentium ratione dolorem reiciendis amet esse debitis nesciunt similique quas
            aliquid officia sapiente temporibus quae laboriosam soluta, quisquam ad inventore, aliquam excepturi assumenda distinctio exercitationem?
            Quod cum qui est eaque itaque obcaecati quibusdam magnam vero temporibus quaerat a ab dolor aliquam quasi incidunt in harum enim, ullam
            asperiores officia! Iusto cum, labore neque enim, eius accusantium accusamus excepturi magni similique officiis, deserunt dicta ipsam
            laudantium aspernatur! Illo autem atque quidem praesentium magnam ipsa eveniet eos repellendus facilis! Quos fuga, debitis aperiam
            voluptatum quia ad ipsum optio.
        </li>
        <li id="Tab1-Q7" class="tab">
            <center>Tab 7<sup>6</sup> Content</center><br/>
            Quas, minima. Architecto, odit. Odio, necessitatibus minus ex voluptatibus reiciendis, sit sequi error fugiat illo expedita vero provident
            ullam exercitationem blanditiis? Labore perspiciatis, eveniet quibusdam quasi facere dolorum dicta commodi, esse, voluptatum et molestias
            cupiditate eligendi cumque saepe totam! Sunt odit optio eum mollitia, repellat libero eius laboriosam nulla eos debitis at veniam! Deserunt
            repellendus, facilis culpa voluptas pariatur debitis error doloribus eius rerum iste amet atque earum, libero magni eos unde itaque officia
            distinctio minus qui voluptate officiis. Mollitia quo neque quis autem molestiae debitis alias culpa recusandae deserunt, reprehenderit illo
            amet aspernatur a, ab fuga perferendis obcaecati dignissimos sequi architecto eaque quas?
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- 2nd -->
<div class="tabs-container">
    <ul class="tabs-stripe">
        <li>1<sup>0</sup></li>
        <li class="active">2<sup>1</sup></li>
        <li>3<sup>2</sup></li>
        <li>4<sup>3</sup></li>
        <li>5<sup>4</sup></li>
        <li>6<sup>5</sup></li>
        <li>7<sup>6</sup></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="tabs-content">
        <li id="Tab2-Q1" class="tab">
            <center>Tab 1<sup>0</sup> Content</center><br/>
            What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard
            dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
            survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the
            1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus
            PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </li>
        <li id="Tab2-Q2" class="tab active">
            <center>Tab 2<sup>1</sup> Content</center><br/>
            Tristique senectus et netus et. Enim praesent elementum facilisis leo vel. Aliquam faucibus purus in massa tempor nec. Eu lobortis elementum
            nibh tellus molestie. Ullamcorper a lacus vestibulum sed. Mattis nunc sed blandit libero volutpat sed cras. Mus mauris vitae ultricies leo
            integer malesuada. Etiam erat velit scelerisque in dictum non consectetur a. Commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis. Sed
            vulputate odio ut enim blandit volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit. Quis auctor elit sed vulputate. Sit amet mauris commodo quis imperdiet.
            Sed viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum enim.
        </li>
        <li id="Tab2-Q3" class="tab">
            <center>Tab 3<sup>2</sup> Content</center><br/>
            Mi sit amet mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa tincidunt. Morbi tincidunt augue interdum velit euismod in. Eget nulla facilisi etiam
            dignissim diam quis enim lobortis. Justo donec enim diam vulputate ut pharetra. Tincidunt arcu non sodales neque. Nec feugiat in fermentum
            posuere. Volutpat consequat mauris nunc congue nisi vitae. Suspendisse sed nisi lacus sed viverra tellus in hac habitasse. Dolor purus non
            enim praesent elementum. Mattis pellentesque id nibh tortor id aliquet lectus proin. Bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel. Nunc sed velit
            dignissim sodales ut eu sem integer. Sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus nec feugiat in. Pulvinar neque laoreet suspendisse
            interdum. Magna eget est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing.
        </li>
        <li id="Tab2-Q4" class="tab">
            <center>Tab 4<sup>3</sup> Content</center><br/>
            Commodi corporis praesentium sapiente cum est, aliquam, libero veniam minus voluptatem officiis odio. Asperiores molestiae explicabo facere
            quia! Possimus ipsum est doloremque accusamus similique non eligendi repellendus? Asperiores illum voluptates sequi reprehenderit quam sunt
            accusamus quo sint tempore perspiciatis facere in, odio dolore dolores obcaecati aut inventore! Veritatis eos facere dolor iure id mollitia
            nisi dicta. Culpa velit ut sequi, nam similique doloribus numquam vitae dolor. Sit cumque et sunt sapiente? Minus quidem reiciendis et,
            harum excepturi esse deserunt eos eligendi ex pariatur, sit, dolorem suscipit architecto praesentium fugit. Possimus nesciunt animi
            aspernatur eveniet delectus incidunt ipsa at illo explicabo! .
        </li>
        <li id="Tab2-Q5" class="tab">
            <center>Tab 5<sup>4</sup> Content</center><br/>
            Dicta ratione magni mollitia assumenda sed enim doloribus repudiandae. Mollitia illo consectetur in iure neque. Non dolore culpa doloremque
            similique natus fuga hic voluptates, temporibus itaque. Hic accusantium quasi atque beatae laborum dolor tempora facere quibusdam animi
            vitae sint exercitationem impedit asperiores consequuntur, eius mollitia deleniti ad eligendi nobis ullam dignissimos sequi at natus earum.
            Officiis, expedita dolore fuga doloremque consequuntur aliquam facilis odit optio modi. Exercitationem dolor reiciendis, aperiam et
            excepturi molestias, cumque ex vel tenetur blanditiis ad eum nesciunt cupiditate autem doloribus quam vero maxime, distinctio sit inventore
            itaque aliquid. Obcaecati architecto odio qui dolore .
        </li>
        <li id="Tab2-Q6" class="tab">
            <center>Tab 6<sup>5</sup> Content</center><br/>
            Placeat, reprehenderit eaque? Totam perspiciatis expedita praesentium ratione dolorem reiciendis amet esse debitis nesciunt similique quas
            aliquid officia sapiente temporibus quae laboriosam soluta, quisquam ad inventore, aliquam excepturi assumenda distinctio exercitationem?
            Quod cum qui est eaque itaque obcaecati quibusdam magnam vero temporibus quaerat a ab dolor aliquam quasi incidunt in harum enim, ullam
            asperiores officia! Iusto cum, labore neque enim, eius accusantium accusamus excepturi magni similique officiis, deserunt dicta ipsam
            laudantium aspernatur! Illo autem atque quidem praesentium magnam ipsa eveniet eos repellendus facilis! Quos fuga, debitis aperiam
            voluptatum quia ad ipsum optio.
        </li>
        <li id="Tab2-Q7" class="tab">
            <center>Tab 7<sup>6</sup> Content</center><br/>
            Quas, minima. Architecto, odit. Odio, necessitatibus minus ex voluptatibus reiciendis, sit sequi error fugiat illo expedita vero provident
            ullam exercitationem blanditiis? Labore perspiciatis, eveniet quibusdam quasi facere dolorum dicta commodi, esse, voluptatum et molestias
            cupiditate eligendi cumque saepe totam! Sunt odit optio eum mollitia, repellat libero eius laboriosam nulla eos debitis at veniam! Deserunt
            repellendus, facilis culpa voluptas pariatur debitis error doloribus eius rerum iste amet atque earum, libero magni eos unde itaque officia
            distinctio minus qui voluptate officiis. Mollitia quo neque quis autem molestiae debitis alias culpa recusandae deserunt, reprehenderit illo
            amet aspernatur a, ab fuga perferendis obcaecati dignissimos sequi architecto eaque quas?
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You seem to have multiple questions, but it's hard to tell exactly because you have supplied them as comments in the code you posted.

Comment: moved questions outside